# What is the difference between these definitions of a sequence converging to some real number?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, definition

D1: Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence. We say that $(a_n)$ converges to $L$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that for every $n>N$ we have $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$.

D2: Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence. We say that $(a_n)$ converges to $L$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that for every $n\geq N$ we have $|a_n-L|< \epsilon$.

D3: Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence. We say that $(a_n)$ converges to $L$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a real number $N$ such that for every $n>N$ we have $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$.

D4: Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence. We say that $(a_n)$ converges to $L$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a real number $N$ such that for every $n\geq N$ we have $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$.

The definitions are equivalent.
Why would one use one definition over the other, is it just a matter of convention?
If this question it too general please provide guidance on how I can improve it, thanks.

Comment: I guess it's sort of just convention.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure D2 is the most commonly used one

Comment: Note that they're also equivalent to four other definitions D1bis, D2bis, D3bis, D4bis where you'd put $\leq \varepsilon$ instead of $< \varepsilon$. So far, D2 and D2bis are the ones I have seen the most, used interchangeably (depending on what's convenient).

Comment: Oh I see you don't have that word in English, my bad. It's a French word that you put after another word to describe something that's very similar, though nowadays it's mainly used with numerotation (housing, math/physics, etc...). But English probably doesn't have an equivalent, whoops.

Comment: @BrunoB Right before you answered me I figured out what it means and deleted my comment. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

When we are dealing with indices of a sequence it is peculiar to compare them to real numbers, so 3 and 4 are strange.  The difference between 1 and 2 is just $1$ in the minimum $N$ you use.  As we only care about whether there is an $N$, not what it is, it doesn't matter which you use.